# If we have installed nltk zip file and then we want to install the setup of the same using the python script

Tags: python, subprocess, azure-machine-learning-service

If we have installed nltk zip file and then we want to install the setup of the same using the python script then how can we do it?

I have created  the zip file and kept all the packages in it and then importing it from python script

```
from mynltk.corpus import *
from mynltk.corpus.reader import *
brown.words()[0:10]
```